# How to exclude file extensions in svn root directory using svn:global-ignores command line

Tags: svn, svn-propset

I'm looking for options to global ignore files and directories, I'm not interested on doing this per-directory, so `svn:ignore` is not an option here, but I can't find the correct syntax for svn:global-ignore rather for listing what's in the config file:

```
svn pg svn:global-ignores  --show-inherited-props
```

I would like to be able to increase the ignore list by adding new entries from svn command line. Any thoughts on this?

I believe following command is supposed to achieve what I want:

```
svn propset svn:global-ignores *.suo .
```

Can someone please check if this works, because it does not for me. Why does it require a target as 2nd parameter (.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot in the end of the command-line specifies the path in your local working copy where you want to modify the versioned property. The dot represents the "PATH..." argument of the example:

```
svn propset PROPNAME [PROPVAL | -F VALFILE] PATH...
```

Nevertheless, I guess that you want to use [`svn propedit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propedit.html), not [`svn propset`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html). `svn propset` does not "add" property values, it completely rewrites them. So if you run the command-line `svn propset svn:global-ignores *.suo .` the resultant property value will be just "*.suo".

Read [Subversion 1.8 Release Notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config) and [SVNBook about this global ignores](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) feature.

*NOTE:* Items that are already in the repository will still be in the repository after you setup the ignore settings. In other words, you can't ignore items that exist in the repository.

*NOTE2:* **Global ignores work only with Subversion 1.8 and newer clients!**